# why result came 2+'2' result is 22 and 2-'2' result is 0?

Tags: javascript

I am checking below expressions
console.log(2+'2')   // 22
console.log(2-'2')   // 0

why not came 2+'2' is 4 ,the above both two expressions are using arithmetic operators???

please guide me

Comment: Good luck brother

Comment: Because [*"the addition operator produces the sum of numeric operands or string concatenation."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition). The other arithmetic operands are defined only for numbers and they convert their operands to numbers before using them.